# Largest floating point number with a factor of 2

Tags: python, floating-point

I am practising python and trying to find the largest floating point number with a factor of 2 that can be displayed by python.

I have tried the following code, however it doesn't run. Can anyone suggestion where the bug is?

```
a=2.
b=1.
infinity = float("inf")
while a < infinity:
    b=a*2.
    if b > infinity:
        break
    if b < infinity:
        a=b*2.
    if a > infinity:
        break

if a < infinity:
    print a
elif b < infinity:
    print b
```

Comment: there is no place on the CPU marked as *here lies infinity*. You are bisecting a diverging sequence. Instead check `sys.maxsize`

Comment: mind you, you don't need looping `sys.float_info[0]` gives you the highest float. It is an even number.

Comment: Yes, but is `sys.float_info[0]` a power of two? I'd expect the max float to be `2^(some_large_number) * 1.1111...11b`, so it would be a hair short of being a perfect power. (although it might not matter that it's a power of two, depending on whether the OP really meant "with a factor of two" or actually meant "with _only_ factors of two")

Comment: @Kevin I said it is an even number (on my machine). Check it `m=sys.float_info[0]` `m%2`. Is the OP looking for powers of two?

Comment: Yes, I agree that the number is even. Your comment answers the question as it was written; I'm just wondering if it answers the question that OP intended to ask. I do think the OP is looking for powers of two, based on the code he's written already. But only the OP knows for sure.

Comment: @Kevin True: the question, as I understand it if I read the sentence, is about the highest even floating point number. However, it contrasts with the code, which looks for the highest power of two

Answer (score 4):

There is no number larger than infinity, so `if b > infinity:` will never be True. Try changing it to `if b == infinity:`, and your program will terminate as desired.

---

Also, you can simplify your script somewhat if you only use one variable:

```
a = 1.0
while True:
    if a*2 == float("inf"):
        break
    a *= 2
print a
```